# Pentax k1000 lens with Nikon d3200?

Tags: lens, nikon-d3200, pentax-k1000

My first camera was a Pentax k1000, can I use the 1 : 2 50mmlens from the Pentax k100 on my Nikon digital SLR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an [adapter like this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=995090&gclid=Cj0KEQjw3auuBRDj1LnQyLjy-4sBEiQAKPU_vchf1FVTCYCndzocuyP-FbdFbCZRfSV6EoZqYlW6XfYaAtFq8P8HAQ&Q=&m=Y&is=REG&A=details) however it has an element in it so you will be at the mercy of the quality of that element. Or you could opt for one with [no element like this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/270870561138?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=82) however because of the big distance from element to sensor that nikon has you will most likely lose infinite focus (thats what the element corrects.

**WARNING:** various makers used various different mechanisms to control the iris. Likewise makers have element to sensor (or film) distances that vary as well as mount depths that vary. There are lots of adapters out there to allow lens X to be mounted on camera Y. HOWEVER these adapters some times DO NOT deal with things that stick out of the center of the lens, lenses that have intrusive (require mirror up) elements or similar things. Even if everything connects snug YOU CAN DAMAGE the mirror of your camera if there is some thing in its way.

So yes you can make it fit but you may (most likely will) lose infinite focus and none of the metering will work in your 3200 with an all manual lens. For what its worth a 1.2 is a pretty fast lens and [Nikon does make one](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/36976-GREY/Nikon_1435_NIKKOR_Normal_50mm_f_1_2.html?gclid=Cj0KEQjw3auuBRDj1LnQyLjy-4sBEiQAKPU_vdJ-F02YnOM2O7R-ltmww6QbdG-NT_zarOiIkm8XCBkaAg_t8P8HAQ&_escaped_fragment_=) (I have it, its great) if you really need that kind of speed. But if you have the lens, the $30 adapter is worth a shot even if you can only use it for close up shots.